# Rails 3 + Devise: New Comment form also containing User model fields?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

The idea is to have what you've seen a million times before, a "post a new comment" form with the following fields (for visitors who are not logged in): Name, Email, Website, and Message

Note the "message" field belongs to the Comment model, and the other 3 belong to the User model.  Since the User model is Devise validatable, I'd like to be able to use those validations (as well as those for the comment field) in this hybrid form.

Is this possible?  Can I add `accepts_nested_attributes_for(:user)` to the Comment model, even though the Comment is the child of User?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you plan to do with the user model fields when a user is not signed in?

Comment: The user fields are only displayed if the user isn't logged in.  If they are logged in, the comment's author (user) is assigned in the comments controller upon "create."

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand you. If the user isn't logged in do you search for a user with the same email and assign them as the comment's author? What if they don't exist? Or do you mean the article's author is assigned to the comment (assuming the comment is being made on an article).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're asking for, but you can do something like this ... make a virtual accessor in your User model for a comment:

```
def with_comment
  if params[:user][:comment]
    @comment = self.comments.build params[:user][:comment]
  else
    @comment = self.comments.build 
  end
end 

def with_comment=(comment)
  self.comments.build comment
end
```

Then in app/views/users/registrations/new.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for(resource.with_comment(params),
             :as => resource_name,
             :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>

   <% f.fields_for :with_comment, resource.with_comment do |cf| %>
      <% cf.text_area :message %>
   ...
```

I haven't tested this but it's adapted from similar working code that I'm using.

This is actually the user form with a comment added. I just let devise do its thing and try not to fight it.